# HMM continuous x, discrete y

Tags: hidden-markov-model

I'm curious about whether an HMM variant is appropriate when I have a continuous x (time series) and a discrete y (emission class.) In context, I have multiple ships, which could be located in one of many discrete geographical regions. For now, let's assume that I have a single ship and want to predict the sequence of geographical regions it might be in. I'm not necessarily against an RNN/LSTM, however, I do need not only most likely class but the probabilities of each class assignment.

Would an HMM be an appropriate sequence-to-sequence model here?

In the multiship context, how might I include them?

An other models you would recommend?

Comment: A very typical HMM has this structure. For example, HMMs are used to extract words (discrete classes) from recorded speech (continuous data). For instance 
[A Tutorial on Hidden Markov Models and Selected Applications in Speech Recognition](https://web.ece.ucsb.edu/Faculty/Rabiner/ece259/Reprints/tutorial%20on%20hmm%20and%20applications.pdf)

Comment: Not sure I understand your terminology; which variable is observed and which is latent? HMMs require a discrete latent variable (a.k.a. state), but the observed variable can be anything you like. Also, time must be discrete, not continuous.